# How do I set the TARGETDIR programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I am creating an MSI package for my application. The requirement is such that if application `A` is installed at client machine, this new set up should install in that application folder. Otherwise it should create its own folder.

I have created custom installer. I have overridden the methods like `OnInstall`, `OnBeforeInstall`, etc. But no effect on `TARGETDIR`.

Even though I write this:

```
this.Context.Parameters["TARGETDIR"] = new_path;
```

It still installs it to old path which is set as `DefaultLocation` property of `ApplicationFolder` Tab of setup project.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What technology are you using to author your MSI? Wix? InstallShield? Visual Studio setup project?

Comment: Visual studio set up project

Comment: Well, just as a warning, it's probably about time to start learning a different technology. VS2010 was the last version of Visual Studio that includes these projects. If you're spending time learning how to do `X` with visual studio setup projects, it's time wasted in terms of future development. I'd usually recommend switching to WiX (if you have the time to learn it) - it's got a bit of a learning curve, but it comes at a great price ($0).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But what would be the quick resolution on this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done in a VS setup project because all custom actions run after the install has (almost) finished, so it's too late to change the install folder. VS setup projects have no support for running CAs early to do this.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can tell me how otherwise we can do this?

Comment: You can't do it with Visual Studio. It doesn't support CAs running before the install folders are used and the files are installed. Use another tool - VS setup projects expose only a small part of the Windows Installer functionality. There is no quick fix for you to do this in your VS setup project.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with a search  if the registry path for that other app is in a registry item.

1. In launch conditions, Search Target Machine, add a registry search for that registry item and it will go into an uppercase property name, it defaults to REGISTRYVALUE1, something like that.
2. In File System view, right click file system on target machine and add special folder, custom folder. Make the default location [TARGETDIR] (it should be that by default) and make the Property that registry property name, that REGISTRYVALUE1.
3. Your files go in that custom folder.

If that works, the files will go to the default target directory in program files unless that path is there, and then they should go in there. However, there's a dialog for users to choose the install folder so I don't know what you plan to do about that.